# Modifying localStorage gives A cross-origin error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I'm making a web application using reactjs, and when development is suddenly this error appears:"A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development".I AuthContext witch gives user data to localStorage :

```
 const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
    
      const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
      const userInfo = localStorage.getItem("userInfo");
      const expiresAt = localStorage.getItem("expiresAt");
    
      const [authState, setAuthState] = useState({
        token,
        expiresAt,
        userInfo: userInfo ? JSON.parse(userInfo) : {},
      });
    
      const setAuthInfo = ({ token, userInfo, expiresAt }) => {
        localStorage.setItem("token", token);
        localStorage.setItem("userInfo", JSON.stringify(userInfo));
        localStorage.setItem("expiresAt", expiresAt);
    
        setAuthState({
          token,
          userInfo,
          expiresAt,
        });
      };
```

Unfortunately i have a problem with updating user details.
In context i made another function:

**Edit:** I forgot to write that after the function is executed userDetails changes to undefined so I get a cross-origin error

```
const setUserInfo = ({  userInfo }) => {
        localStorage.removeItem("userInfo");
        localStorage.setItem("userInfo", JSON.stringify(userInfo));
        

        setAuthState({
          userInfo,
        });
      };
```

I have rest-api route to update-details , exemplary response:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "user": {
        "role": role,
        "_id": id,
        "username": name,
        "email": email,
        "createdAd": createdAt,
        "__v": 0
    }
}
```

And user rest-api response when user login, example:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "token": token,
    "expiresAt": expiresAt,
    "userInfo": {
        "role": role,
        "_id": id,
        "username": name,
        "email": email,
        "_id": id
    }
}
```

Updating details working when i call it but after  i get cross site error.

And heres Submit function

```
const handleUpdate = async (info) => {
    setError("");
    setLoading(true);

    try {
      const { data } = await fetchContext.authAxios.put(
        "http://localhost:5000/api/v1/auth/update-details",
        info
      );
      const user = data.user;
      console.log(user);
      auth.setUserState(data);
      setError(null);

      setLoading(false);
    } catch (err) {
      setLoading(false);
      // const { data } = err.response;
      // setError(data.error);
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i dumb

```
const setUserInfo = ({  userInfo }) => {};
```

should be

```
const setUserInfo = ( userInfo ) => {};
```